# IIS 404 Not Found for only SOME resources...same permisions set

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7.5, asp.net, mime-type

I am pretty stumped because IIS is returning 404 not found for a handful of resources, but not others. I checked the permissions to make sure they are set exactly the same way.  The paths are also the same, all in an assets folder.  The Build Action is set to Content, and set to Copy Always to the output directory.  All the files are on the server in the correct path, yet for a handful I get 404 not found.  The folders are also set with the correct permissions...

[image]

EDIT:
The mime type on the ones not being loaded seems to be text/html instead of text/css or application/x-javascript...they are written the same way though in my html, and I have the following in my htaccess file:

```
AddType text/x-component .htc
AddType text/css .css
AddType application/x-javascript .js
```

And for the resources, this one loads properly:

```
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-validate/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This one does not load properly:

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery-ui-1.11.0.custom/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: What's the file extension on the ones that won't load?

Comment: I have a couple that end in .js and a couple that end in .css that are not loading